# Checkstyle length check for import statements

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

How to remove checkstyle violation if it throws a "Line is longer than 80 characters" for an import statement?

Comment: A workaround is to surround the import block with `//CHECKSTYLE:OFF` ...imports... `/CHECKSTYLE:ON`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Talking of aesthetic issues, the very aim of checkstyle is to have a beautiful code, (wow coding and beauty). Adding tags would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Not in my experience; checkstyle gives you bolshevik code, all straight and uniform. And I've **never** managed to use it without the tags.

Answer (score 5):

Remove:

```
<module name="LineLength">
    <property name="max" value="80"/>
</module>
```

from your checkstyle configuration.

**EDIT:**

Disable it only for imports:

```
<module name="LineLength">
   <property name="ignorePattern" value="someRegex"/>
</module>
```

You have to provide the regular expression which finds the line starting with `import` into the `value` attribute. I am not so good at regex so you will need work out the regular expression yourself.

The regex like: `...value="^import"...` should work. But not tested.

Comment: This removes it for all statements not just the import statement?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis: this will remove it from all the statements. please suggest something savvyyyy

Comment: In the same vein, remove Checkstyle from your project.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis: for this i have to change my checkstyle file. Isn't there no way to break import file names, like we do with if or String...

Answer (score 1):

To exclude `import` and `package` statements from the check, you can apply following configuration:

```
<module name="LineLength">
    <property name="max" value="80" />
    <property name="ignorePattern" value="^(package|import) .*"/>
</module>
```

Source: https://checkstyle.org/config_sizes.html#LineLength_Examples

Or you can apply tags as suggested by Marko (but first option is more proffered):

```
// CHECKSTYLE:OFF
import ...
// CHECKSTYLE:ON
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some aditional info to Paulius Matulionis's answer.
If you are using default Checkstyle rules, you can find checkstyle configuration file by going to your Idea directory:

%HOMEPATH%.IdeaIC2017.1\config\plugins\CheckStyle-IDEA\classes\sun_checks.xml

Folder name ".IdeaIC2017.1" could be different depends on version of Idea you are using.

Also, you can find your configuration file name in Idea's ["Settings"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a2EB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Checkstyle `LineLength` configuration ignores package and import statements.  This is accomplished by the default value for the [`ignorePattern`](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_sizes.html#LineLength_Properties) property, which is `"^(package|import) .*"`.

Since your import statement is failing the `LineLength` check, either it's formatted differently than expected by the default configuration (e.g. it has a leading space), or you've customized the `ignorePattern` in your project, (inadvertantly) removing the `import` check configuration in the process.

Import statements can be added back to a customized `ignorePattern` regex.  For instance, if it's currently set to `"somePattern"`, you could configure your `ignorePattern` as follows:

```xml
<module name="LineLength">
  <property name="ignorePattern" value="^import .*|somePattern"/>
</module>
```